# Search for hash in an array by value

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, perl-data-structures

I have a function which extracts Excel data into an array of hashes like so:

```
sub set_exceldata {

    my $excel_file_or = '.\Excel\ORDERS.csv';
    if (-e $excel_file_or) {

        open (EXCEL_OR, $excel_file_or) || die("\n can't open $excel_file_or: $!\n");                   
        while () {

            chomp;
            my ( $id, $date, $product, $batchid, $address, $cost ) = split ",";
            my %a = ( id      => $id
                    , date    => $date
                    , product => $product
                    , batchid => $batchid
                    , address => $address
                    , cost    => $cost
                    );
            push ( @array_data_or, \%a );
        }
        close EXCEL_OR;
    }
}
```

Populating the array of hashes is fine. However, the difficult part is searching for a particular item (hash) in the array. I can't seem to locate items that might have an id or 21, or a batchid of 15, or a cost > $20 etc.

How would I go about implementing such a search facility?

Thanks to all,

Comment: You could just push an anonymous hash ref push(@array,{ id => $id });

Comment: While not directly related to your question, you should look at Text::xSV for parsing the .csv file. Just doing a split on "," is not 100% reliable for parsing. There is also a Spreadsheet::ParseExcel module that can parse Excel binaries.

Answer (score 22):

With the power of [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html)

```
my @matching_items = grep {
  $_->{id} == 21
} @array_data_or;
```

If you know there will be only one item returned you can just do this:

```
my ($item) = grep {
  $_->{id} == 21
} @array_data_or;
```

(Untested, and I haven't written one of these in a while, but this should work)

Comment: Thanks for your insight David. 

Regarding your solution this returns an array of results whereas because there will really only be one occurence is should return a hash and not an array. Would this solution still be valid when returning a hash instead of an array of hashes?

Comment: if you're sure it will return only one value you can use $matching_items[0], or do 

my $matching_items = (grep {
  $_->{id} == 21
} @array_data_or)[0];

Comment: @DidYouJustDoThat: Assuming that there is only one match is not necessarily safe. Some of your examples (e.g. cost > 20) could return multiple items.

Answer (score 5):

If you're sure that the search always returns only one occurence or if you're interested in only the first match then you could use the 'first' subroutine found in [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/Scalar-List-Utils-1.21/lib/List/Util.pm)

```
use List::Util;

my %matching_hash = %{ first { $_->{id} == 21 } @array_data_or };
```

I enclosed the subroutine call in the **%{ }** block to ensure that the RHS evaluates to a hash.

Comment: The %{} around the call to first() dereferences the hashref from the array, making a (shallow) copy. That could be a problem depending on how the OP uses it. I'd return the hashref instead: `$hr = first {$_->{id} == 21} @array_data_or`

Comment: I too would prefer to return and later use the hashref but according to DidYouJustDoThat's comment to David Doward's reply, the poster is looking for a hash and not a reference.

Comment: I think saying "hash" is just sloppy terminology. He wants a single value instead of a list.

Comment: Could be, that's why I added the RHS line at the bottom to clarify what I was doing so that the OP could use either the reference value or the entire hash.