# How can I fetch a hash ref from array of hashes by one of its values?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, reference, perl-data-structures

I have a array of hashes, each hash containing same keys but values are unique. On the basis of particular value, I need to store hash ref.

See the below example to understand it properly:

```
my @aoaoh = (
            { a => 1, b => 2 },
            { a => 3, b => 4 },
            { a => 101, b => 102 },
            { a => 103, b => 104 },
    );
```

Now I will check if a hash key `a` contains value `101`. If yes then I need to store the whole hash ref.

How to do that?

Comment: You can get some idea from thread at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934225/search-for-hash-in-an-array-by-value

Comment: @ppant : thanks, link is also useful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
my $key = "a";
my ($ref) = grep { $_->{$key} == 101 } @aoaoh;
```

or using `List::Util`'s `first()`:

```
use List::Util 'first';
my $ref = first { $_->{$key} == 101 } @aoaoh;
```

Comment: Or if you might have more than one with `a == 101`... `for my $href (grep {$_->{'a'} == 101} @aoaoh) { ### Do something with $href here }`

Comment: Is important to define the variable like a list (of one scalar), using parenthesis around the variable. For example: my ($ref).

Answer (score 2):

Earlier, I was using `foreach` for fetching the `Hash ref` like

```
foreach my $href (@aoaoh){
     foreach my $hkeys(keys %{$href}){
           if(${$href}{$hkeys} == 101){
              my $store_ref = $href;
           }
     }
}
```

Now after taking help from eugene, i can do it like

`my ($hash_ref) = grep {$_->{a} == 101 } @aoaoh;`

or in general way (when we dont know the key) then use

```
my ($hash_ref) = grep { grep { $_ == 101 } values %$_ } @aoaoh;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `first` method is fine and what I'd use if I only wanted to do this once or twice. But, if you want to do this many times, it's probably better to write a lookup table, like so:

```
my %hash_lookup;
foreach my $h ( @aoaoh ) { 
    foreach my $k ( keys %$h ) { 
        $hash_lookup{$k}{ $h->{ $k } } = $h;
    }
}
```

Then you find your reference like so:

```
my $ref = $hash_lookup{ $a_or_b }{ $value };
```